# How to store CNN extracted features to train a SVM classifier

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Using the 2D CNN shown below to extract features from images, how I can store the extracted features in order to train an SVM to classify the features?

Model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(3, 150, 150)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(4))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

Extracting features with:

```
layer_name = 'layer_name'
intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input,
                                 outputs=model.get_layer(layer_name).output)
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(data)
```

Steps:

- Storing these extracted features from my image dataset in order to train an SVM classifier.
- Using `train_test_split()` to split the train and test data
- Train the classifier:

  ```
  clf = svm.SVC()
  clf.fit(X, y)
  ```

I need to know how to do this.

Comment: You can try h5py, or np.save, etc....

Comment: Why don't you save the output in a pickle? https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Comment: Can provide me with code example, please? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try saving and loading them as HDF5 file format. It has several advantages over pickle. It's much faster to save and load (especially for large arrays).

To do so, you need to install **h5py** package. Example codes for saving and loading are as follows:

**For saving:**

```
import h5py
h5f = h5py.File('your_file_name.h5', 'w')
h5f.create_dataset('layer_model', data=intermediate_layer_model)
h5f.create_dataset('output', data=intermediate_output)
h5f.close()
```

**For loading**

```
import h5py
h5f = h5py.File('your_file_name.h5', 'r')
intermediate_layer_model = h5f['layer_model'][:]
intermediate_output = h5f['output'][:]
h5f.close()
```

Comment: Is there any way to save features for an entire dataset or should i extract one image at time?

Comment: Of course, you can save them at once. For example, if you are extracting 64 features from each image (say a total of 1000 image), you can store it as a 1000x64 numpy array in an HDF5 file.

Answer (score 0):

This article will help you extract features using a CNN model.

https://www.kdnuggets.com/2018/12/solve-image-classification-problem-quickly-easily.html/2

You'll have the extracted features of all the images in a numpy array. Then you can decide to store it as a CSV file or any other file format like HDF5.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).