# How to split dataset to implement svm classifier after extracting features from Inception v3 transfer learning?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning

The training dataset consists of 42848 images in 4 (classes) subdirectories.

```
image_size= [520,578] 
BATCH_SIZE= 32
```

Model:

```
inception = InceptionV3(input_shape=CROP_SHAPE + [3], weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
for layer in inception.layers:
layer.trainable = False
x = inception.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
prediction = Dense(len(folders), activation='softmax')(x)
```

Here's the model summary.

```
 Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)           [(None, 520, 578, 3  0           []                               
                                )]                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d (Conv2D)                (None, 259, 288, 32  864         ['input_1[0][0]']                
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization (BatchNorm  (None, 259, 288, 32  96         ['conv2d[0][0]']                 
 alization)                     )                                                                 
   
                                                                                                 
 mixed9_1 (Concatenate)         (None, 14, 16, 768)  0           ['activation_87[0][0]',          
                                                                  'activation_88[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_1 (Concatenate)    (None, 14, 16, 768)  0           ['activation_91[0][0]',          
                                                                  'activation_92[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 activation_93 (Activation)     (None, 14, 16, 192)  0           ['batch_normalization_93[0][0]'] 
                                                                                                  
 mixed10 (Concatenate)          (None, 14, 16, 2048  0           ['activation_85[0][0]',          
                                )                                 'mixed9_1[0][0]',               
                                                                  'concatenate_1[0][0]',          
                                                                  'activation_93[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 global_average_pooling2d (Glob  (None, 2048)        0           ['mixed10[0][0]']                
 alAveragePooling2D)                                                                              
                                                                                                  
 dense (Dense)                  (None, 1024)         2098176     ['global_average_pooling2d[0][0]'
                                                                 ]                                
                                                                                                  
 dropout (Dropout)              (None, 1024)         0           ['dense[0][0]']                  
                                                                                                  
 Feature_extractor (Dense)      (None, 64)           65600       ['dropout[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 dense_1 (Dense)                (None, 4)            260         ['Feature_extractor[0][0]']      
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 23,966,820
Trainable params: 2,164,036
Non-trainable params: 21,802,784
__________________________________
```

I've extracted features from Inception v3 model. Now I want to split the features using sci-kit learn to train SVM classifier.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
model_feat = Model(inputs=loaded_model.input,outputs=loaded_model .get_layer('Feature_extractor').output)
feat_trainX = model_feat.predict(train_data)

...

X_train2, X_test2, y_train2, y_test2 = train_test_split(feat_trainX, train_gen, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
```

[image]

Here, the "traingen" directory iterator is used as a "label" but getting inconsistent values. I've also got same problems using "tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory".

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_gen = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/content/DeepSeagrass/Training',
    target_size=CROP_SHAPE,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    shuffle=True,
    class_mode='categorical')


Found 42848 images belonging to 4 classes.
```

Is there any solution to labeling large image dataset for training discriminative algorithms?
It seems that flow_from_directory and tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory both takes the data as small batch randomly which may cause inconsistency between features and label.
Now, the main question is how tackle this situation by using less gpu. I'm using google colab which gets out of memory on gpu runtime if I want to convert the whole dataset into numpy array.

Also, if yes then how to save the features with label in CSV file for further visualization like TSNE plot?

Below references I've found but neither gave exact solution:

1. [How to store CNN extracted features to train a SVM classifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50359055/how-to-store-cnn-extracted-features-to-train-a-svm-classifier)
2. [How to implement t-SNE in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71500106/how-to-implement-t-sne-in-tensorflow)
3. https://pyimagesearch.com/2019/05/27/keras-feature-extraction-on-large-datasets-with-deep-learning/

Comment: What is the shape of `feat_trainX` and `train_gen`? Can you update your question with how you defined your model? `flow_from_directory` probably won't work that well with `train_test_split()` based on the random nature of the datagen. Do you need to use `flow_from_directory`? Can you load everything in memory? The error trace is saying you're trying to pass 42848 features with only 1339 labels.

Comment: Yes, without flow_from_directory I can't process the train and test data , it'll be out of memory during execution if I take whole dataset even if the batch size cross more thatn 50 images.  train_gen - consists of 42848 images belonging to 4 classes.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the issue is you're using `flow_from_directory()` with `batch_size` smaller than the entire input, which is why it's only producing 1339 elements at a time (because it's in batches). The number of items in `Dataset` created from `flow_from_directory()` is `total_number / batch_number`. Either set the batch number with `flow_from_directory()` to be one (1), or load all the images into memory before `train_test_split()`. Either one of those will load everything in memory.

It's also worth noting `train_gen` is not an array, it's a `Dataset`, which means it contains `x` and `y` values. You most likely aren't trying to get both feature *and* labels there, right? If you need one or the other, you'll need to debug and look into that variable. Whenever I do, they contain arrays `x` and `y`, corresponding to features and labels, respectively. Some people don't see it named that way. You could technically do it this way, but like my comment, given the random nature of `flow_from_directory()`, it probably won't be as robust as loading all in memory (because some could get skipped, some could get picked multiple times).

Comment: Yeah, that's correct if I set batch size more than 50 then it's get out of memory during execution in google colab on gpu runtime. Is there any way to overcome this runtime isssue using colab. I don't have higher configuration to process this large dataset.

Comment: Use batch size less than 50.

Comment: already mentioned batch size =32. but give inconsistent values during splitting in scikit learn to extract a particular layer

Comment: `train_test_split()` isn't for `tf.data`, tensorflow has its own methods for creating training and validation sets, along with ways to get a test set.